# Flex wrap and items with flex basis 100% causes extra space

Tags: css, flexbox

In the example I've provided, I would ideally like the first column to only be as large as its text content (so no space between the columns). It seems to be getting extra space based on the height as the space increases/decreases as I add/remove items. I found this documentation which suggests this is how flex-basis: auto works https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flex-basis. Is there a way to prevent the height causing this issue without entirely changing the implementation to use flex-direction or CSS Grid?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item-full-width {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-container-wrap">
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
      </div>
      <div>Test Item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So the current issue is that there is a space with Test Item??

Comment: @RahulIssar So there are two columns I'd ideally like no space between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the wrap-container `flex-direction:column`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  border:1px solid rebeccapurple;
}

.flex-item-full-width {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-container-wrap">
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item Long Version</div>
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
        <div class="flex-item-full-width">Test item</div>
      </div>
      <div>Test Item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay thanks if it's not possible to do this without flex-direction I can accept this :)

Answer (score -2):

In order to receive the spacing you could do something like this:

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Test Item</div>
  <div class="column">Test item</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Test Item</div>
  <div class="column">Test item</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 4%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```